# is appassembler plugin broken for java service wrapper on windows 64bit?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, appassembler, java-service-wrapper

I'm developing on 32bit windows and am using appassembler to create a java service wrapper assembly, and it works ok. But I need to also create a 64bit assembly for deployment to a dev server. In the following config I have substituted the 32bit platform with the 64bit, see the `<includes>` section. But it no longer places the wrapper jar and dll in the lib folder. If I omit the includes completely, I get linux, solaris, Mac OSX and Win32 libraries, but no win64.

Anyone got this working?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>${project.build.directory}/appassembler</target>
                <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                <defaultJvmSettings>
                    <initialMemorySize>256M</initialMemorySize>
                    <maxMemorySize>1024M</maxMemorySize>
                </defaultJvmSettings>
                <daemons>
                    <daemon>
                        <id>MyApp</id>
                        <mainClass>com.foo.AppMain</mainClass>
                        <platforms>
                            <platform>jsw</platform>
                        </platforms>
                        <generatorConfigurations>
                            <generatorConfiguration>
                                <generator>jsw</generator>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>windows-x86-64</include>
                                </includes>
                                <configuration>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>set.default.REPO_DIR</name>
                                        <value>../../repo</value>
                                    </property>
                                </configuration>
                            </generatorConfiguration>
                        </generatorConfigurations>
                    </daemon>
                </daemons>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-daemons</goal>
                        <goal>create-repository</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The community version of the Java Service Wrapper included by the plugin does not have a Windows 64 version available (it must be purchased from the http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/ site).

Answer (score 2):

[Someone](http://www.krenger.ch/blog/java-service-wrapper-3-5-14-for-windows-x64/) has built the 64-bit Windows version that you can download.  Or you can [build](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1635188&group_id=39428&atid=425190) it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/.
It's trying to be compatible reimlementation of Java Service Wrapper that has free 64-bit support.